# Spring Boot - inject from application.yml and application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, yaml

If I inject a list/map with `@Vaule`, it works when I `application.properties`, but it fails if I convert to `application.yml`.

**application.properties**

```
list=1,2,3
map={"1":"1","2":"2","3":"3"}
```

**Example of the class**

```java
@Value("${list}")
private List<String> list;
@Value("#{${map}}")
private Map<String, String> map;

System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(map);
```

**output**:

```
[1, 2, 3]
{1=1, 2=2, 3=3}
```

If I switch to yml (ignore the prefix 'my')

```yaml
my:
  list: [ "1","2","3" ]

  map:
    "1": "1"
    "2": "2"
    "3": "3"
```

It failed with @Vaule, I konw can use a Configuration class like this.

```java
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class MyConfiguration {
    private List<String> list;
    private Map<String, String> map;
}

// failed
@Value("${my.list}")
private List<String> list;
@Value("#{${my.map}}")
private Map<String, String> map;

// success
@Autowired
private MyConfiguration myConfiguration;
System.out.println(myConfiguration.getList());
System.out.println(myConfiguration.getMap());
```

> But I still wonder why I can not use `@Value` to inject list/map by yml.

7.15 update

When structure `yml` like this

```
list: [ "1","2","3" ]
map:
  "1": "1"
  "2": "2"
  "3": "3"
```

It will be parse to

```
list[0]=1
list[1]=2
list[2]=3
map.1=1
map.2=2
map.3=3
```

So when use `@Value("${list}")`/`@Value("#{${map}}")`, will get `NULL`.
But I can get the correct value when I use `@Value("${list[0]}")`/`@Value("${map.1}")`

Comment: Hi, I think if you want to use the @Value annotation you need to structure your yml file like that

list: 1,2,3
map: '{"1":"1","2":"2","3":"3"}'

Comment: Well, it works!

Answer (score 0):

The YAML does not contain the same property names.

For example `list` in the application.properties is defined as `list=1,2,3`, but in the YAML you wrapped them into the `my` field. In this case the YAML name is `my.field`.

If you want to use the same name for `@Value` you could:

- prefix the properties into `application.properties` by using `my` example: `my.list`
- unwrap the YAML and put them into an upper level. example:

```
      list: [ "1","2","3" ]
      map:
        "1": "1"
        "2": "2"
        "3": "3"
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. When I wrapped them into the `my` field. I use `@Value("${my.list}")`, it still failed.